# Python: building complex nested lists within a dictionary

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, nested

I am looking at building lists of lists within a dictionary from an Excel spreadsheet.

My spreadsheet looks like this:

| source_item_id | target_item_id | find_sting | replace_sting |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| source_id1 | target_id1 | abcd1 | efgh1 |
| source_id1 | target_id1 | ijkl1 | mnop1 |
| source_id1 | target_id2 | abcd2 | efgh2 |
| source_id1 | target_id2 | ijkl2 | mnop2 |
| source_id2 | target_id3 | qrst | uvwx |
| source_id2 | target_id3 | yzab | cdef |
| source_id2 | target_id4 | ghij | klmn |
| source_id2 | target_id4 | opqr | stuv |

My output dictionary should looks like this:

> ```
> {
>   "source_id1": [{
>       "target_id1": [{
>           "find_string": "abcd1",
>           "replace_string": "efgh1"
>       },
>       {
>           "find_string": "ijkl1",
>           "replace_string": "mnop1"
>       }]
>   },
>   {
>       "target_id2": [{
>           "find_string": "abcd2",
>           "replace_string": "efgh2"
>       },
>       {
>           "find_string": "ijkl2",
>           "replace_string": "mnop2"
>       }]
>   }],
>   "source_id2": [{
>       "target_id3": [{
>           "find_string": "qrst",
>           "replace_string": "uvwx"
>       },
>       {
>           "find_string": "yzab",
>           "replace_string": "cdef"
>       }]
>   },
>   {
>       "target_id4": [{
>           "find_string": "ghij",
>           "replace_string": "klmn"
>       },
>       {
>           "find_string": "opqr",
>           "replace_string": "stuv"
>       }]
>   }]
> }
> ```

With the following code I only get the last values in each of the lists:

> ```
> import xlrd
> xls_path = r"C:\data\ItemContent.xlsx"
> book = xlrd.open_workbook(xls_path)
> sheet_find_replace = book.sheet_by_index(1)
> find_replace_dict = dict() 
> for line in range(1, sheet_find_replace.nrows):
>     source_item_id = sheet_find_replace.cell(line, 0).value
>     target_item_id = sheet_find_replace.cell(line, 1).value
>     find_string = sheet_find_replace.cell(line, 2).value
>     replace_sting = sheet_find_replace.cell(line, 3).value
>     find_replace_list = [{"find_string": find_string, "replace_sting": replace_sting}]
>     find_replace_dict[source_item_id] = [target_item_id]
>     find_replace_dict[source_item_id].append(find_replace_list)
> print(find_replace_dict)
> ```

--> result

> ```
> {
>     "source_id1": ["target_id2", [{
>         "find_string": "ijkl2",
>         "replace_sting": "mnop2"
>       }
>     ]],
>     "source_id2": ["target_id4", [{
>         "find_string": "opqr",
>         "replace_sting": "stuv"
>       }
>     ]]
> }
> ```

Comment: Out of curiosity - this is a bit orthogonal - is there a reason that `source_idx` points to a list of dictionaries, each with one key only (`target_idx`)? It might feel more natural to have that be a dictionary instead of a list, with a key-value relationship.

Comment: The errors are most likely in the last three lines of the for loop; I'm pretty sure you are over-writing dictionary values here. I'd advise running this through a debugger and checking the output at each step. Worst-case: use print statements to print the values of `find_replace_list` and `find_replace_dict`.

Comment: Are you using an older version of Python? `xlrd.open_workbook` seems to fail in Python 3.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is rather complicated by the fact that you have a list of single-key dictionaries as the value of your source ids, but you can follow a pattern of parsing each line for the relevant items and, and then using those to target where you insert appends, or alternatively create new lists:

```
def process_line(line) -> Tuple[str, str, dict]:
    source_item_id = sheet_find_replace.cell(line, 0).value
    target_item_id = sheet_find_replace.cell(line, 1).value
    find_string = sheet_find_replace.cell(line, 2).value
    replace_string = sheet_find_replace.cell(line, 3).value
    return source_item_id, target_item_id, {
        "find_string": find_string,
        "replace_string": replace_string
    }

def find_target(target: str, ls: List[dict]) -> int:
    # Find the index of the target id in the list
    for i in len(ls):
        if ls[i].get(target):
            return i
    return -1  # Or some other marker

import xlrd
xls_path = r"C:\data\ItemContent.xlsx"
book = xlrd.open_workbook(xls_path)
sheet_find_replace = book.sheet_by_index(1)
result_dict = dict() 
for line in range(1, sheet_find_replace.nrows):
    source, target, replacer = process_line(line)
    # You can check here that the above three are correct
    source_list = result_dict.get(source, [])  # Leverage the default value of the get function
    target_idx = find_target(target, source_list)
    target_dict = source_list[target_idx] if target_idx >=0 else {}
    replace_list = target_dict.get(target, [])
    replace_list.append(replacer)
    
    target_dict[target] = replace_list
    if target_idx >= 0:
        source_list[target_idx] = target_dict
    else:
        source_list.append(target_dict)

    result_dict[source] = source_list

print(result_dict)
```

I would note that if `source_id` pointed to a dictionary rather than a list, this could be radically simplified, since we wouldn't need to search through the list for a potentially already-existing list item and then awkwardly replace or append as needed. If you can change this constraint (remember, you can always convert a dictionary to a list downstream), I might consider doing that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am getting an Unresolved reference 'Tuple' and Unresolved reference 'List' for the process_line and find_target functions respectivly.

Comment: In looking at how I need to use this dictionary, making the source_id a dictionary instead of a list is also possible, especially if it is going to make it more simple. Thanks once again.

Comment: @Genspec You might need to `from typing import Tuple` and List, etc. Or you can drop the type hinting.

Comment: Thanks @Nathaniel, This is now working. I had to make a minor change in the find_target:
    for i in ls:
        if ls[len(ls)-1].get(target):
            return len(ls)-1